# Using function least and greatest on timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion

How can I use function least/greatest in PostgreSQL on timestamp column?
I have a column - plc_time (timestamp without time zone) and I need to select rows where the plc_time is greatest from two values (the value is timestamp without time zone).
Should I use the conversion? How can I do it?

Comment: I have an answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select *
from some_table
where plc_time = greatest(timestamp '2013-07-15 14:55:00', timestamp '2013-03-01 17:43:00');
```

Comment: Thank you, it's works. I do not know why my question is rated negatively.

Comment: @bemol: I assume because "*it does not show any research effort*". The syntax and usage of the greatest() function can easily be looked up in the manual.

Comment: But in the manual I did not find what you showed me.  [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html)

Comment: the manual is not the most explicit